# Will, Wills, Willed, Willed to

Tags: will-would

I am almost completely broken with **"will"**. Can anybody explain it in a good way?

We can use **"will"** for willingness:

*He will work - he wants to work*

*I will sleep - I want to sleep*

*She won't walk with them - she doesn't want to walk with them*

At the same time I am finding some examples of using will like **"wills"** or **"willed"**:

*If he wills to work, then let him do it*

*If anyone wills to do his will...*

*She willed herself not to think of the man...*

If we can use **"will"** both like a **modal verb** which is not conjugatable and a **normal** conjugatable **verb** then what is the difference in:

*He will work - he wants to work*

*He wills to work - he wants to work*

*He willed to work - he wanted to work*

*He would work - he wanted to work*

Comment: In *she willed herself not to think of the man*, the *herself* is important. The idea of willing someone to do something - or something to happen - wishing for it to happen in a very forceful way, as if you thought you could make it happen by the power of the mind. So *he willed himself to work* means he tried very hard to get himself to work (i.e. he didn't want to), and *he wills...* is the same apart from the tense.  but is trying hard to motivate himself. In *if he wills to work...* and *if anyone wills to do his will*, *wills* is somewhere between *wants* and *intends*, but this use is...

Comment: ... obsolete today - you might find it in poetry or wordplay but it is not part of ordinary everyday English.

Comment: Okay, what about simpler exmaples? 1) He will work - he wants to work 2) He wills to work - he wants to work. What is the difference here without "himself-herself"?

Comment: *He wills to work* does not make sense - there is a missing object. *He willed his computer to work* or *he willed her plan to work* would be OK. The meaning is quite different from *he wanted his computer to work* or *he wanted her plan to work* - I can't explain it any better than I did in the first comment above.

Comment: "Will" has many meanings in English.  A complete answer would be far too long.

Comment: So, you can use "will" like a usual verb (willed to\wills to) only there is some object about which you have a will to do something? If there is no object, it's an odd meaning which is pretty archaic, right?

Comment: Will does not equal willingness. Perhaps I will sleep only when I pass out. Perhaps he will work only with a gun to his head.

Answer (score 2):

As an auxillary "will" indictates a future tense.  It doesn't mean "want" it just describes a future act.  There may be some nuance implied by the context but in general "will" is the simplest way to speaking about the future.

> He will work  (doesn't indicate whether he wants to or not. It just describes a future act)

As a main verb "to will" is a rather rare and dated way of saying "wish or desire that something happens."  Don't use this meaning, though you might recognise it in a few idioms.

> Do what you will.

There is a third meaning, which is related to the noun "will", meaning "The ability to make a choice and stick to it". We can use this as an adjective "strong willed" meaning "able to make decisions and keep promises"

> She willed herself not to think of the man  (She used her ability to choose not to think of the man (even though she wants to think of him))

The past tense form "would" has multiple meanings, for example it is used in conditional sentences.

So:

> He will work  (simple future tense)
>
> He wills to work (don't use this)
>
> He wills himself to work (He uses his "will" to choose to work (even though he doesn't want to))
>
> He would work (if he was able to)
>
> John broke his leg and **won't** be able to work. He used to work and he **would** work if his leg was better.  He **will** be in bed for weeks, but his leg **will** get better, and he knows he **will** go back to work. While his leg is broken he enjoys playing video games and he doesn't want to go back to work. But he knows that unless he works, he **won't** get any money. So when his leg is fixed, he **wills** himself to get up and go to work. John is not weak-**willed**

Answer (score 1):

As you've realised, *will* is both a modal and (far less commonly) a lexical verb.

The modal can be used with its usual range of modal meanings (one of which is futurity), or (with emphasis, or in the negative) with the same meaning as the lexical verb: "exert one's will".

As a lexical verb, it is normally followed by a full infinitive clause (i.e. including a subject) - *She wills him to win*.

I do not find its use with a simple *to*-infinitive to be grammatical (*"She wills to work")